# why auth its not working in my validation and its showing anything wrong

Tags: laravel-5.6

im just new in laravel and i dont know whats wrong with my code its not redirecting

```
public function login(Request $request){
   $this->validate($request, [
    'email'=> 'required|max:32',
    'password'=> 'required|confirmed|max:32|min:8',
  ]);
  if (Auth::attempt(['email'=>$request->email,'password'=>$request->password])) {
    return redirect('/welcome');
  }
  return "Oooops something wrong happen";
}
```

this my  login form

```
<form action="login" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="email" name="" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="password" name="" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your password">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="submit" name="" value="login" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">
        </div>
```

and my route

```
Route::post('/login', 'UserController@login');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form is wrong, your name values are empty, and you're missing the confirmation password field

```
<form action="login" method="post">
       {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="password" name="passowrd" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your password">
        </div>  <div class="form-group">
          <input type="password" name="passowrd_confirmation" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your password">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="submit" value="login" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">
        </div>    
</form>
```